# Infinite loop when using a GeometryReader and Padding

Tags: swift, swiftui, geometryreader

I have a two `Text` components inside a `VStack` and I'm using `GeometryReader` to match their widths.

The problem is if I apply `padding` AFTER setting `frame` to the `Text` with the shorter content, I run into an infinite loop.

I want to understand why this is happening. My expectation is that it should just take the larger width and then apply padding to it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var containerWidth: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Shorter Text")
                .frame(width: containerWidth, alignment: .center)
                .background { Color.green }
                // this is `padding` is causing an infinite loop
                .padding(.leading, 5)

            Text("Really really long text")
                .background {
                    Color.yellow
                }
        }
        .background {
            Color.red
        }
        .readSize { size in
            containerWidth = size.width
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

extension View {
    func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}

private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

I tried switching around the application of `padding`. This prevents the infinite recursion of width calculation but does not add the padding.

Comment: There are simpler ways to achieve this without using a `GeometryReader`. Would that help?

Comment: @AshleyMills happy to hear the simpler ways

Answer (score 1):

Let's breakdown why it hangs:

1. At first 1st Text width = nil, which means it has its own width
2. 'readSize' sets the width, which forces VStack to resize
3. VStack got resized, so 'readSize' sets width again

This is how I would do it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var containerWidth: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Shorter Text")
                .readSize { storeWidth($0.width) }
                .frame(width: containerWidth)
                .background { Color.green }

            Text("Really really long text")
                .readSize { storeWidth($0.width) }
                .frame(width: containerWidth)
                .background { Color.yellow }
        }
        .background { Color.red }
    }

    func storeWidth(_ value: CGFloat) {
        containerWidth = max(value, containerWidth ?? -.infinity)
    }
}
```

Like this 'readSize' will execute once, because Texts don't change their widths. Order of modifiers is important, that's why frame(width:) is put after 'readSize'

Comment: applying padding causes an infinite loop :(

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 16+ Layout Protocol**

This may not be the simplest answer to code from scratch but the following is Apple's recommended solution for these types of problems.

*"I run into an infinite loop. I want to understand why this is happening."*

In WWDC22's "[Custom Layout with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10056/)" (18:18) that is explained:

> Geometry Reader is designed to measure its container view and report
> to its subview. The information flows downward. Sending the
> information up the view hierarchy is bypassing the Layout engine which can
> result in a loop. The reader measures the layout and changes the
> frame, which might change the layout, which could require another
> measurement and so on.

The Layout Protocol is recommended for this type of problem. Apple provides a solution to a nearly identical problem in the video above starting at 7:40.

The following is an example closely based on their provided code. A struct called MyEqualWidthVStack adopts the Layout Protocol. This is how that layout struct would be used in your example. Notice that each text frame is set to a max width that will fill the available space. MyEqualWidthVStacke will calculate the available space for each Text as the width of the widest text field:

```
struct LayoutView: View {
    var body: some View {
            MyEqualWidthVStack {
                Text("Shorter Text")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background { Color.green }

                Text("Really really long text")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background { Color.yellow }
            }
            .background { Color.red }
    }
}
```

The Layout Protocol requires two methods, sizeThatFits and placeSubviews. The sizeThatFits method returns a size that the layout container needs to arrange its subviews. The placeSubviews method places the subviews, in this case, in a vertical stack:

```
struct MyEqualWidthVStack: Layout {
    /// One of two required methods for the Layout Protocol
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout Void) -> CGSize {
        guard !subviews.isEmpty else { return .zero }
        
        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        let totalSpacing = spacing.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
        
        return CGSize(
            width: maxSize.width,
            height: maxSize.height * CGFloat(subviews.count) + totalSpacing)
    }
    
        /// Second of two required methods for the Layout Protocol
    func placeSubviews(
        in bounds: CGRect,
        proposal: ProposedViewSize,
        subviews: Subviews,
        cache: inout Void
    ) {
        guard !subviews.isEmpty else { return }
        
        let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
        let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
        
        let placementProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: maxSize.width, height: bounds.height)
        var nextY = bounds.minY + maxSize.height / 2
        
        for index in subviews.indices {
            subviews[index].place(
                at: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: nextY),
                anchor: .center,
                proposal: placementProposal)
            nextY += maxSize.height + spacing[index]
        }
    }
    
        /// Finds the largest ideal size of the subviews.
    private func maxSize(subviews: Subviews) -> CGSize {
        let subviewSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }
        let maxSize: CGSize = subviewSizes.reduce(.zero) { currentMax, subviewSize in
            CGSize(
                width: max(currentMax.width, subviewSize.width),
                height: max(currentMax.height, subviewSize.height))
        }
        
        return maxSize
    }
    
        /// Gets an array of preferred spacing sizes between subviews in the
        /// vertical dimension.
    private func spacing(subviews: Subviews) -> [CGFloat] {
        subviews.indices.map { index in
            guard index < subviews.count - 1 else { return 0 }
            
            return subviews[index].spacing.distance(
                to: subviews[index + 1].spacing,
                along: .vertical)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make two views the same width in a `VStack` (or other container), there's no need for a `GeometryReader`, just use

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

on the container. In the code below I've added `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` modifiers to each `Text` to make sure they take up all available space.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Shorter Text")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.green)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
            Text("Really really long text")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(.yellow)
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        .background(.red)
    }
}
```

[image]

Here's the same but with `.padding(.leading, 5)` *before* the `.frame` modifier

[image]

Comment: Such an elegant solution and seems to work well with other UI types, orientations and all iOS13+ versions. Kudos.